# how to edit certain charcters in a string specified in a command line in java

Tags: java, string

i have to do this as an assignment, but nothing i do is working im either bombarded with error or i cant use if statements (we didnt learn them yet)

the assignment is the following:

Write    a   method  mangle that     accepts     a   string  str,    a   character   c and   an  integer     n   as 
arguments,   such    that    the     string  str contains    at  least   n   times   the     character   c.      The     method 
returns  the     resulting  string  after    removing    the     first  n   occurrences of   the    character   c from   the
original    string  str (the    method  should  not print   anything    to  the console).   The signature   of  the 
method  should  be:
public  static  String  mangle(String   str,    char    c,  int n)
Use  this    method  to  write   a   program     StringMangle.java that  takes   as  command     line
arguments   an  integer N   followed    by  N   tuples; each    tuple   consists    of  a   string, a   character   and an
integer  (str,  c,  n). The program should  print   each    of   the    strings after    removing    the     first  n
occurrences of  the character   c   from    the corresponding   string  str.
Sample  Run:

> java    StringMangle    3   test    t   1   ahaaaamad   a   4   testtt  t   2
>   est hamad   estt

Comment: Show us the code you have (edit the question and paste it in, indented by 4 spaces), then we can help you figure out what you did wrong. Right now your question looks like a "write the code for me" request, and that will be rejected by the community.

Comment: What's with all the tab characters in the question text???

Comment: i wasnt even using the correct commands so if someone can show me how to solve it it would be really apreciate it... i have a test in 5 hours and i havent slept i really need to know this as soon as possible

Comment: We're not going to write the code for you. If you procrastinate until 5 hours before test, that's your own fault. We can help you with your code, but you have to write some relevant code first, and show it to us, so we know you at least have made an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to use String.replaceFirst() to replace all values of variable 'c' with a blank.

Then iterate as many times as your variable n

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replacefirst.htm